# Connecting sql developer with netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a data miner workflow created in sql developer. It is connected to oracle 11g r2 database. The workflow has a classification model to predict the values of new data. For the moment I can right click on the model node and run the application to get the predictions. I also have a standalone application developed in NetBeans IDE. There I have managed to connect the application to the same oracle database and retrieve values and insert new values to the table which the previously mentioned classification model is connected. Now what I want is to run the classification model in sql developer from a button click event in my java application instead of manually going and running the model inside sql developer. So I would like to know whether it is possible to pass commands to sql developer through a java application. After a big search so far this is the only information I was able to find regarding connecting both softwares.
https://community.oracle.com/thread/550144?start=0&tstart=0
But it doesn't quite talk about my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can right click the end component of work flow and get the script of the work flow.

Then  use that script in DAO layer of your Application  with correct String concatenation.